# How do I use boost.lambda with boost.thread to get the thread's return value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lambda

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
using boost::thread;

int add(int a, int b) {return a+b;}

int sum, x=2, y=6;
thread adder(var(sum) = add(_1, _2), x, y);
adder.join();
cout << sum;
```

I get a compile error:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::arg' to 'int'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re really close actually!  The problem is that you’re directly calling add() with Lambda’s placeholders—it’s not being evaluated lazily inside the lambda, but right away.

Here’s a fixed version:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
using boost::thread;

int sum, x=2, y=6;
thread adder(var(sum) = _1 + _2, x, y);
adder.join();
cout << sum;
```

And if you really want to use the `add` function, you'd use `bind`:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
using boost::thread;

int add(int a, int b) {return a+b;}

int sum, x=2, y=6;
thread adder(var(sum) = bind(add, _1, _2), x, y);
adder.join();
cout << sum;
```

Comment: And to delay invocation of a function call, use `bind`.

Comment: I definitely need to use the function, the 'add' example is a gross simplification. :) But I tried your syntax for: `thread adder(var(sum) = bind(add, _1, _2), x, y);`
I get an error on MSVC 9 (boost 1.43). Trimmed to fit:

`boost/lambda/detail/function_adaptors.hpp(260) : error C2664: 'int (int,int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'rt2' to 'int'
        with
        [
            Result=int,
            Func=int (int,int),
            RET=int,
            A2=rt1,
            A3=rt2,
            Arg1=int,
            Arg2=int,
            A1=rt1,
            I=2
        ]`

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot `using boost::lambda::_1;` etc. I wonder why I didn't get some more revealing error. I'm not even sure which _1/_2 that I had in scope! I don't have any using namespaces for boost or std.

Comment: Make sure you're using boost::lambda::_1 -- there are a number of places that _1 is defined in Boost so it's easy to use the wrong ones.  I think that will fix your problem.