# Retrieve return value with lambda from boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost

Lately I read this post:
[How do I use boost.lambda with boost.thread to get the thread's return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971286/how-do-i-use-boost-lambda-with-boost-thread-to-get-the-threads-return-value)

I tried to implement the answer and it went fairly well except I get an error that I can't solve.

My code is this:

```cpp
falcon::Mesh* falcon::ResourceManager::GetMesh(const std::string& id)
{
    Mesh* meshPtr;
    boost::thread meshLoadThread(boost::lambda::var(meshPtr) = bind(&MeshManager::LoadMesh, MeshManager::GetInstance(), id));
    meshLoadThread.join();
    return meshPtr;
}
```

But when I try to compile, I get the following error

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 
    'const std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>'
 to 'falcon::Mesh *'
```

I know it should work normally because in the example it works too!
Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Gives me a similar error, instead it's not std::tr1::bind now, but boost::bind

Error 1 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' to 'falcon::Mesh *'

Comment: I accidentally deleted my earlier comment. I added an answer that I think should fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `bind` from `std::tr1` (the version that comes with Visual Studio).

You need to use the version of `bind` that is part of the `Boost.Lambda` library, i.e. `boost::lambda::bind`. Note that this is not the same as `boost::bind`.

You will need to `#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>`.

Comment: You are sure it is boost::lambda::bind, because here it says "bind is not a member of boost::lambda"

Comment: Finally, it compiles, thanks for your help! Finally got an answer to this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

How about using C++11x lambdas instead?

```
boost::thread meshLoadThread([&](){ meshPtr = MeshManager::GetInstance().LoadMesh(id); });
```

Comment: hmm, I'll have a go at this one too ;)